# Missing Attribute Tags in Magento's production creation

Tags: php, magento

I was following this tutorial http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/ and everything was going smoothly, however I realised that my magento doesn't have a "website" or "bundled item" tab on the left hand side navigator. Is there a setting or something I need to add to make it run?

I'm working off Magento 1.7.0.2 and when I try the tutorial on another Magento website it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the configuration of my Magento was not set correctly. I had to replace the "Bundle" folder inside the main Magento folder to make it work.

1. Download a default stock standard Magento
2. Take the Bundle Folder from (App >> code >> core >> Mage)
3. Copy/Replace it with the existing